# How to hide the directory in prompt if directory has no change?

Tags: zsh, ps1

Can the prompt be hidden if the directory has no change after the last command executed? Show only the `$`, show the path only if the directory was changed in the last command.
My ps1:

```
precmd () { __git_ps1 "%B%F{blue}$shellEmulator%f%F{cyan}%3d%f%b" "%F{green}
$ %f" "|%s"}
```

The shell I am using is zsh.

Comment: Why would you like that? That would just be annoying. For example, you run `dir` and then you'll have to scroll up to see where you are if you forget

Comment: Hello, which shell? Add it as a tag please.

Comment: Because  my screen is small, and I am finding way to press less `c-l`, umm... maybe a silly reason.

Comment: precmd is _not_ ps1, but it seems like a good place to start – have you tried adding anything into it yet? e.g. making it store the current $PWD?

Answer (score 0):

I think `precmd()` is a good starting point. A minimalistic proof-of-concept could be:

```
precmd() {
  if [[ $PWD_PREV == $PWD ]]; then
    PS1="$ "
  else
    PS1="%~ $ "
    PWD_PREV=$PWD
  fi
}
```